# Sudo command not found when change PATH

Tags: linux, command, redhat, sudo

I have problem with sudo command when i changed $PATH 
Problem:

```
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: tty: command not found
-bash: uname: command not found

[root@ol6 ~]# sudo
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

And echo $PATH

```
[root@ol6 ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/bin
```

Could you tell me solve this problem.
thanks sm.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23572/bash-sudo-command-not-found

Comment: @joaumg I don't think this is the same problem as that link (and that link is technical on a different site anyway so wouldn't strictly be a dupe), because this problem is likely because `PATH` got messed up, while the link is about a system that seemingly doesn't have `sudo`

Comment: @EricRenouf yes, u right.

Comment: This question isn't really about programming though, so it would probably be better asked at the [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) sister sites

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is located in `/usr/bin` on **RedHat**, but I think your real problem is that you single-quoted `$PATH` when you altered your PATH and got a literal `$PATH` in it instead of what you intended!

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/bin

Comment: I only change this PATH and got this problem

Comment: If you changed the PATH in a file, you should undo your change.  Logout and login again to get the system default path.  Do `echo $PATH` to see what it is and make a note of it in case you need to get back to it again.

Answer (score 1):

You somehow got the literal string `$PATH` in your `PATH` variable, when you probably meant to add some stuff before and after it.  I imagine you did this by using single quotes when assigning:

```
PATH='/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/bin'
```

when you should have used double quotes

```
PATH="/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_66/jre/bin"
```

so the `$PATH` would expand to its current value (though it's too late for that in your current shell).

Anyway, for me, `sudo` is in `/usr/bin` so if you don't have that in your path you won't be able to run it without specifying the full path.

Comment: When use /usr/bin/sudo apt-get update : sudo: apt-get: command not found. How can i reset $path to default?

Comment: I thought you said this was redhat, `apt-get` is a Ubuntu command, try `yum` on RedHat type systems.  The easiest way to fix your `PATH` is probably just to exit that shell and login again.  If you can't do that, you can make a reasonable estimate that PATH was probably something like `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Ok, i changed my PATH but still error: 
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: tty: command not found
-bash: uname: command not found.
Now i can use sudo

Comment: Those are in `/usr/bin` on my system, same as `sudo`, so if that's in your `PATH` I would expect it to find them, you can try to get more info by running `command -v id` to see what it thinks it should do when you try to run `id`, perhaps there's a function/alias that's confounding things?  `uname` is in `/bin` for me for what that's worth